# Problems with fire simulation

Tags: smoke-simulation

Why is my fire so transparent? The problem only occurs in a scene that I've been working on for over a month.

[image]

The problem does not occur when I do this in a clean scene.

[image]

How can I increase its density? The videos I watched online didn't have this problem, so I didn't find an option to adjust the density.

[image]
(Blender v 3.3.0)

Comment: Hello could you please share the file (only the domain and the inflow)?

Comment: @moonboots Yes, of course https://blend-exchange.com/b/goS0jEdw

Comment: If I increase the Blackbody Intensity or the Temperature of the Principled Volume, and also change the Blackbody tint to an orange for example, it works fine

Comment: the weird thing is that you can get what you show in your second picture with the exact same settings...

Comment: @moonboots I must be making the same mistake somewhere, because I model these "woods" over and over again and get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the biggest factor of how visible your fire look is actually its surrounding light. The more light you have around, the more your fire is hard to see:

[image: ambient light comparison]

In your case, you have a very bright and flat ambient lighting everywhere, cast by your world shader. In reality, that stove wouldn't be so lit inside unless there's a direct light source, like the sun at the right angle or a fire. So, the first thing to fix should be that, make your light more "accurate". Reduce your world's intensity, and use actual light objects to light up your scene. Plus it gives you more control to make it look lively!

Also, because you are rendering on Eevee, shader emission is very limited. So it will be very hard to make your fire look like it emits light in the oven and outside without adding light objects in the first place. (And, thought Cycles doesn't need light objects to emit light from volumes, at the end of the day it's still a simple way to tweak the appearances to your liking!)

You could also add *Light Probes* > *Irradiance Volume* objects here and there to help the renderer.

For the fire itself, what you can do is to bump up the blackbody intensity a bit, like 5.

[image: fixed fire]

If you want to keep this flat lighting, you can always make the temperature  way more intense than it should.

Here's a final result on Eevee:

[image: final eevee]

And for comparison's sake, Cycles with the same setup:

[image: fixed cycles]

---

Bonus point:

The Principled Volume's default temperature is 1000 Kelvin, which though still a bit red-ish, it is technically correct for a wood fire, and it's a round number easy to remember.

But if you are interested in playing with the color a bit, or doing fires with other fuels, or just animating a fire at different stages, it's interesting to look up to the ignition and average hot fire temperatures of your fuel material.

Wood:

- Ignites at about 575 Kelvin = 301,85 Celsius / 575,33 Fahrenheit
- average hot fire at 1200 Kelvin = 926,85 Celsius / 1700,33 Fahrenheit

[image: different temperatures]

Comment: I think it's EEVEE problem. Because a second ago I pressed the F12 button, the fire was not visible at all, after pressing F12 again, the fire became visible, although I changed absolutely nothing. There are no such problems with Cycles.

Comment: The current fire simulation system have issues fetching the cache during render, updating the render task or making a change in the scene forces fetching again.